# Ruby Hash.new with a block need in-depth explanation

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm looking at the solution to a problem called `duped_index` and I'm not quite getting the concept of this particular Hash.new variable:

```
def duped_index(arr)
    result = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

    arr.each_with_index do |ele, idx|
        result[ele] << idx
    end

    result.select { |alphabet, indices| indices.length > 1 }
end

p duped_index(["a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "b", "c", "d", "b"]) => # {"b"=>[1,4,5,8], "c"=>[2,3,6]}
```

Could you explain to me what's going on in between the Hash.new block?
Would there be a more efficient way to solve this exercise in general?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions)". We need you to provide us more information about the problem you're having. Where did you research this? What did you try when experimenting and trying to understand it, and why didn't that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

**You could write your code with no bells or whistles**

```
def duped_index(arr)
  result = {}
  arr.each_with_index do |ele, idx|
    result[ele] = [] unless result.key?(ele)
    result[ele] << idx
  end
  result.select { |ele, indices| indices.length > 1 }
end
```

```
duped_index(arr)
  #=> {1=>[0, 2, 5], 2=>[1, 4]}
```

**Another way is create empty arrays on the fly, as needed**

```
def duped_index(arr)
  result = {}
  arr.each_with_index { |ele, idx| (result[ele] ||= []) << idx }
  result.select { |ele, indices| indices.length > 1 }
end
```

```
duped_index(arr)
  #=> {1=>[0, 2, 5], 2=>[1, 4]}
```

Ruby's parser expands the *abbreviated assignment* `result[ele] ||= []` to:

```
result[ele] = result[ele] || = []
```

If `result` does not have a key `ele`, `result[ele] #=> nil`, so

```
result[ele] = nil || = []
  #=> []
```

If `result` has a key `ele` `result[ele]` remains unchanged. Therefore,

```
(result[ele] ||= []) << idx
```

causes `idx` to be appended to the array (empty or otherwise) that is the value of `result` for the key `ele`.

This method would more commonly be written as follows:

```
def duped_index(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(ele, idx), result|
       (result[ele] ||= []) << idx }.
      select { |ele, indices| indices.length > 1 }
end
```

**A third way is to create a hash with a default proc, as in the question**

Suppose:

```
result = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  #=> {}
```

Now perform the following operation:

```
result['dog'] << 'woof'
  #=> ["woof"] 
result
  #=> {"dog"=>["woof"]}
```

When `result['dog']` is executed Ruby sees that `result.key? #=> false`, so she executes the block, first by assigning values to the block variables:

```
hash, key = [result, 'dog']
  #=> [{}, 'dog']
hash
  #=> {}
key
  #=> 'dog'
```

Then executes:

```
hash['key'] = []
```

resulting in:

```
result
  #=> { 'dog'=>[] }
```

She then executes:

```
result['dog'] << 'woof'
result
  #=> {"dog"=>["woof"]}
```

Now suppose we execute:

```
result['dog'] << 'I love kibble!'
result
  #=> {"dog"=>["woof", "I love kibble!"]}
```

This time Ruby sees that `result` has a key `'dog'`, so she simply appends `"I love kibble!"` to the array `result['dog']`, without referencing the block.

Let's take another example:

```
result = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  puts "I just launched the missiles...just kidding"
  hash[key] = []
end
```

```
result['dog'] << 'woof'
I just launched the missiles...just kidding
  #=> ["woof"]
```

The behaviour is the same as before except a message is displayed as well. The point is that you can put any code you like in the block, extracting data from database being an example (though I don't think that's a common use of default procs).

The method using this form of [Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) would commonly be written:

```
def duped_index(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.
      with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |(ele,idx), result|
        result[ele] << idx }.
      select { |ele, indices| indices.length > 1 }
end
```

The choice of which approach to take is mainly a matter of taste, but I expect most Rubyists would elect #2 or #3.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

Default values are a way to declare a static or dynamic value for Hash keys without having to explicitly assign to each key ahead of time. Pragmatically, this is often used to ensure that some sensible value is returned for all new keys without requiring an explicit assignment to each key created.

Your code uses the block form of Hash initialization to set the default value. I explain the block form below, and then contrast it with two simpler examples.

### Setting a Default Value with a Block

In Ruby, a Hash object can be instantiated in a number of different ways. One way is to pass a block to [Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new). This block will be called for any key that doesn't have a value.

Consider this related example:

```
# define a default value using a block
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

# block dynamically assigns empty array
# to new keys
h.has_key? 'foo' #=> false
h['foo']         #=> []
h.has_key? 'foo' #=> true
```

Here, *h* is assigned a new Hash object with a block. This block basically assigns an empty Array object as the "default value" for new members of the Hash that are not given explicit values. In practice, this means the value returned by the block when a previously-unassigned key is looked up will be `[]`.

Now consider:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

# block does nothing for assigned keys
h.has_key? 'bar' #=> false
h['bar'] = nil
h['bar']         #=> nil
h.has_key? 'bar' #=> true
```

Note how assigning a value (even nil) sets the expected value. The default value is really only used when making the first access to a key that doesn't already exist.

### Why Use a Block?

A block declaration is generally more useful when you want to calculate the default value at runtime, or when the default value for new keys should be dynamic. For example:

```
# define some variable that will change
@foo = 0

# declare a Hash that dynamically calculates
# its default value
h = Hash.new { @foo + 1 }

h['foo']  #=> 1
@foo += 1
h['bar']  #=> 2
```

Unless you need that additional flexibility, though, you could just as easily have passed an Array literal to the constructor instead. For example:

```
# sets default values to `[]` instead of invoking
# a block each time
h = Hash.new []
```

Unless you expect your default value to change for different keys in your hash, it's often semantically clearer to assign a single object as the default value rather than a block.

### See Also: Hash#fetch

Another way to get similar behavior to a default value is to use the block form of [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch). For example, given a Hash without a default value, you can still declare a default when you do a key lookup:

```
h = {}
h.fetch 'foo', []
#=> []
```

The semantics and use cases for #fetch are different than #new, but in an example like yours the practical results should be the same. The approach you take will ultimately just depend on what you're trying to express with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have addressed the `Hash.new` magic, so here's a minimal solution of sorts:

```
def duped_index(list)
  list.map.with_index.group_by(&:first).values.select do |l|
    l.length > 1
  end.map do |l|
    l.map(&:last)
  end
end
```

Here `list.map.with_index` converts the list into `[["a",0],["b",1],...]` where it's a value and index pair. This is grouped by the first value into a hash of the form `{"a"=>[["a",0]],"b"=>[...]}` where each pair is grouped by its first entry.

We're only interested in the grouped `values`, and of those to `select` those values of `length` greater than `1`.

Once that's been filtered, strip off the original value and extract just the `last` entry of each pair, the index.

Where it produces:

```
p duped_index(["a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "b", "c", "d", "b"])
# => [[1, 4, 5, 8], [2, 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) for Hash#new is a bit bewildering. Normal behaviour for a hash is to respond with `nil` when it is accessed with a key which it does not contain. "Not in the book". Sometimes this is not sufficient.

The code in the Hash.new block is run when the hash is accessed with a key it does not (yet) has. It gives you the parameters |h,k| (the hash itself and the new key) to work with. So a simple Hash could be written as `h = Hash.new{|h,k| nil }`

In this case, when the hash is "asked" for the first char key "a", we don't want `nil`, we want a new key "a" added to the hash with an empty array as value, where we can add an index to. The block provides this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Hash::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) documentation:

> #### new → new_hash
>
> #### new(obj) → new_hash
>
> #### new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash
>
> Returns a new, empty hash. If this hash is subsequently accessed by a
>   key that doesn’t correspond to a hash entry, the value returned
>   depends on the style of `new` used to create the hash. In the first
>   form, the access returns `nil`. If *obj* is specified, this single
>   object will be used for all *default values*. **If a block is specified,
>   it will be called with the hash object and the key, and should return
>   the default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value
>   in the hash if required.**
>
> ```
> h = Hash.new("Go Fish")
> h["a"] = 100
> h["b"] = 200
> h["a"]           #=> 100
> h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish"
> # The following alters the single default object
> h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH"
> h["d"]           #=> "GO FISH"
> h.keys           #=> ["a", "b"]
>
> # While this creates a new default object each time
> h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" }
> h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish: c"
> h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH: C"
> h["d"]           #=> "Go Fish: d"
> h.keys           #=> ["c", "d"]
> ```